# Not good print HTML after load page

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example you're booking this hotel, after select room[s] hotel You must fill out the form[s].

This example, You have selected a room.

```
lenHotel = 1;
plusCapacity = 2;
```

‍Script:

```
$(function () {
for(var i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++) {
    $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').append(
        "<h4>" + (i + 1) +" .Room Name</h4>" +
        "<div class=\"box-content\">" +
        "<div class=\"field-row clearfix\"> " +
        "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"name\" id=\"name\"> " +
        "</div><div class=\"field-row clearfix\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-6\"><select id=\"country\">" +
        "<option value=\"0\">Select Country</option><option value=\"1\">Country name</option><option value=\"2\">Country name</option>" +
        "</select></div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-6\">" );

    if(hotel[i]['plusCapacity'] != 0) {

        $("#Step-02").find('.col-xs-6').append(
            "<select id=\"addPeople\">" +
            "<option value=\"0\">add people</option>"
        );

        for(var j = 0; j < hotel[i]['plusCapacity']; j++) {
            $(".col-xs-6").find('#addPeople').append(
                "<option value=\"' + j + '\">' + j + '</option>"
            );
        }
    } else {
        $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').append(
            "<div class=\"col-xs-6\"><select id=\"addPeople\" disabled>" +
            "<option value=\"0\"> The opt-out add </option>"
        );
    }
    $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').append("</select></div></div></div><hr />");
}
})
```

I just want to this HTML:

```
<div id="information-box">
<h4>1. Room name</h4>
<div class="box-content">
    <div class="field-row clearfix">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="field-row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select id="country">
                <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                <option value="1">country name</option>
                <option value="2">country name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select id="addPeople">
                <option value="0">add people</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But, after print from script:

```
<div id="information-box">
    <h4>1. Room name</h4>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div class="field-row clearfix">
            <input id="name" placeholder="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="field-row clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <select id="country">
                    <option value="0">Select country</option>
                    <option value="1">country name </option>
                    <option value="2">country name</option>
                </select><select id="addPeople">
                    <option value="0">add people</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <select id="addPeople">
                    <option value="0">add people</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Twice! print `addPeople` ... what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here that you use **class** selector that find all your DOM **col-xs-6** classes related.

In you case you have `.find()` query function that found two matches in the DOM and that the reason you see that in two places, where you have an equal classes name of **col-xs-6**.

Try to indicate you query to the place you want to place the data:

```
 $("#Step-02").find('.col-xs-6').last().append(
       "<select id=\"addPeople\">" +
       "<option value=\"0\">add people</option>"
 );
```

[Last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) - can help you here.

[code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgoNmE)

Answer (score 1):

First look shows me few problems in your code.

You should make jQuery understand that where exactly you're trying to append the code. Because jQuery finds the fist element and append there only.

Use `.eq()` to find the index of `col-xs-6`.

`$("#Step-02").find('.col-xs-6:eq(1)')` instead of

```
$("#Step-02").find('.col-xs-6').append(
    "<select id=\"addPeople\">" +
    "<option value=\"0\">add people</option>"
);
```

Still, I would not suggest you to manipulate your DOM in loop. You should use a variable as a String and do concatenation in loop and then append it.

**Example**

```
for(var i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++) {
    var tempString = "";
    tempString += "<div>";
    tempString += "<select></select>";
    tempString += "</div>";

    //Append to the container
    $('.container').append(tempString);
}
```

FYI, this is just an example about how to append long HTML in for loop, you can make necessary changes as per your need.